# Troubles with qfacebookconnect

Tags: c++, qt, facebook

i Have been given this simple task ,

I want to connect to facebook in my code, any how i downloaded QfacebookConnect from here:

http://gitorious.org/qfacebookconnect/qfacebookconnect/trees/master

please check the link above before you reply ....

I just wanted to run the sample so i could make sure that everything is fine and i can continue working in my project but an error occured , its a bit weird

```
:-1: error: ../debug/libqfacebookconnect.a: No such file or directory
```

here is the .pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2009-11-20T00:54:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += network webkit xml

    TARGET = sample
    TEMPLATE = app
    DESTDIR = ../debug

    SOURCES += main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp

    HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

    FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


    INCLUDEPATH = ../inc/
    win32:LIBS += ../debug/libqfacebookconnect.a
    unix:LIBS += ../debug/libqfacebookconnect.so


       symbian: {
        TARGET.CAPABILITY = NetworkServices # Symbian specific, we just need network access
        TARGET.UID3 = 0xA89FA522 # Symbian specific, unprotected uid3 from symbiansigned.com

        INCLUDEPATH += /epoc32/include/stdapis # this seems to be a bug.
        LIBS += -lqfacebookconnect

        libqfacebookconnect.sources = qfacebookconnect.dll
        libqfacebookconnect.path  = \sys\bin
        DEPLOYMENT += libqfacebookconnect
        }

    ICON = gfx/fb.svg
```

its a bit weird that i got this error since i did not mess with anything yet ....

**EDIT:**

i managed to solve the issue , the thing is that i have a new problem after i do the authentication the following appears :

```
Load   successfull for:   QUrl( "http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=199471070112099&next=fbconnect://success&display=touch&return_session=0&fbconnect=1&canvas=0&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request&_rdr" )  
Load started:   QUrl( "http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=199471070112099&next=fbconnect://success&display=touch&return_session=0&fbconnect=1&canvas=0&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request&_rdr" )  
Load  un successfull for:   QUrl( "http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=199471070112099&next=fbconnect://success&display=touch&return_session=0&fbconnect=1&canvas=0&legacy_return=1&method=permissions.request&_rdr" )
```

can you tell me what the problem ???

**Please be Specific in your answer ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not that weird:

When you download the qfacebookconnect project, you only have the sources but no library. You need the library to actually use it, unless you include the source files in your own project. You will get it if you build the qfacebookconnect project.

As the error message is saying it cannot find the .a file, my assumption is that you didn't build the qfacebookconnect project. Another reason could however be that the file is actually called `qfacebookconnect.lib` instead of `qfacebookconnect.a`.

You should be able to open the `libqfacebook.pro` file in Qt Creator in order to build it. If that doesn't work you will have to do it on the command line using `qmake` together with make/nmake/whatever, dependent on your compiler.

Comment: well i opened the  libqfacebook.pro and i clicked build all and it didn't work out.

how can i use make/nmake ... please be specific

Comment: As I don't know which compiler etc you are using, I have to assume you are using a standard installation of Qt Creator with the gcc compiler. In that case, open a command line (Start->Run-> type in "cmd", hit Enter), navigate to the .pro file, type in `qmake`. WHen that's done, type in just `make`. If you have any problems right here I really recommend reading a C++ tutorial..

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\karim\Qt\qfacebookconnect-qfacebookconnect-master\qfaceboo
kconnect-qfacebookconnect>qmake -o Makefile libqfacebook.pro
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to have a `QTDIR` environment variable pointing to your Qt installation and you need to have `%QTDIR%\bin` in your `PATH` environment variable. Otherwise Windows can't find "qmake" if you type it anywhere in your command line